# Can't get jwt token after login

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

**Background**

I am tryng to do an simple authtentication system using jwt and mysql+sequelize here

**What I had being able to do so far**

I am being able to login and generate a token after that.

**Problem**

After being logged in, when I try to check the jwt token with a middleware on a particular route, it simply says that the token was not found.

**What I tried to do**

Since the token should be found at the req.headers['x-access-control'] or ['authorization'] I tried to console.log(req.headers) when I call the middleware but there is nothing about these two headers... Then I think that the problem might be there, but I have no idea on how to solving this :(

**Pieces of code**

This is the middleware (userController.js) which I use to login (signIn) and to verify the token  (verifyToken)

```
var bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
var jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const config = require("../config/config");
const User = require("../models").User;

module.exports = {
  signIn(req, res) {
    console.log("Sign-In");
    User.findOne({
      where: {
        email: req.body.email
      }
    })
      .then(user => {
        if (!user) {
          return res.status(404).send("User not found");
        }
        var passwordIsValid = bcrypt.compareSync(
          req.body.password,
          user.password
        );
        if (!passwordIsValid) {
          return res
            .status(401)
            .send({
              auth: false,
              accessToken: null,
              reason: "Invalid Password"
            });
        }
        var token = jwt.sign({ id: user.id }, config.secret, {
          expiresIn: 86400 // expires in 24 hours
        });
        res.status(200).send({ auth: true, accessToken: token });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send("Error =>" + err);
      });
  },
  verifyToken(req, res) {
    console.log(req.headers);
    let token =
      req.body.token ||
      req.query.token ||
      req.headers["x-access-token"] ||
      req.headers["authorization"];
    if (!token) {
      return res.status(403).send({
        auth: false,
        message: "No token provided"
      });
    }
    jwt.verify(token, config.secret, (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send({
          auth: false,
          message: "Fail to Authentication. Error -> " + err
        });
      }
      req.userId = decoded.id;
      next();
    });
  }
};
```

and here is the app.js file with the Routes

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = new Sequelize("mydb", "root", "Metin.234", {
  host: "localhost",
  dialect: "mysql"
});
sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connection with sequelize has been established successfully");
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error("Unable to connect", err);
  });

const userController = require("./controllers").user;

var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("home");
});

app.get("/register", (req, res) => {
  res.render("register");
});

app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  res.render("login");
});

app.post("/login", userController.signIn);

app.get("/showAll", userController.verifyToken);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("server started!");
});
```

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated! =D

**EDIT**
I saved the token on a variable called globalToken, so then it could be used on the verify token function (**EDIT 2** and it works fine for what I want), however I am wondering on how can I get the value of accesstoken that is inside the response object that I am sending after the login proccess.

Comment: From what I can see, you're sending `accessToken` in the response JSON object. Are you sending it back either in body, query or as a header from the frontend to the `/showAll` endpoint?

Comment: Can you share your front-end code?

Comment: Also please dont use `req.headers["x-access-token"]`, instead use `req.get('x-access-token')`. The req.get is case insensitive, so if someone sends you `X-Access-Token` it will be still returned by that function.

Comment: You sent it as globalToken and you are looking for it as token, if I understand, is that what you are doing? Doesn't authorization come prefixed with 'Bearer token'?

Comment: @AbhishekBiswal I did console.log to check all of those and I could not find the access token at all

Comment: @Curt yes I can but I dont think it is relevant at all

Comment: @tksilicon I saved as "globalTOken" and then I could use it inside the middleware, and it is working fine at this way. 
The problem is, I saw on several places that when you are about to verify the jwt token you usually get the value of it by getting the req.headers('x-access-token') or req.headers('authorization'), but when I console.log(req.headers), no one of these headers are even there. I want to know, after I do jwt.sign where the hell the token is going then for me to access it?

Comment: @libikI tried that but it is not returning the token at all :(

Comment: @RogerPeixoto Express / Node doesn't really store the JWT token, when you make the user login, you are sending `accessToken` to the frontend, save that access token (e.g. localStorage) and send it in the subsequent requests like `/showAll?token=<yourTokenHere>`.

Comment: @RogerPeixoto, see this example: https://github.com/narenaryan/node-jwt-integ/blob/master/middleware.js, and the medium tutorial. https://medium.com/dev-bits/a-guide-for-adding-jwt-token-based-authentication-to-your-single-page-nodejs-applications-c403f7cf04f4